# Clone Server to home windows computer

Tags: 12.04, backup, rsync, clone

My goal is to clone my ubuntu 12.04.5 - Server and send the files compressed to my windows computer over the internet. I am using ssh/putty to connect to my server.

How do I compress and send the files at the same time to my home computer without taking up much space on my server?

Comment: You mean a full image of the server?

Comment: That's going to be *real* slow over SSH.

Comment: All files that are not system files that can be easily recreated.

Comment: if you want to use scp / sftp you could try [winscp](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php)

Comment: @Ziazis What about the compression part?

Comment: Did you manage to get it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the tool [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php) you can copy it to your windows machine. It might be a little slow though.

To create only one big file which would drastically increase the speed you would just need to create a tar.gz file of the files you want to transport.

`tar -czf backup.tar.gz /path/to/file /path/to/file ....`

Connect with WinSCP and copy it to your local drive.

You can also preserve permissions with `-p` etc. if you want more information look up the manual of tar with `man tar`.